# Changing Text And Font using Jquery

Tags: jquery

**I am using the following code for 

1) Display the changed content in DIV container so if someone types in textbox it should simultaneously display the typed content

2) on selection of fonts, font should be applied to that content**

**But its not working not sure what wrong i am doing ?**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<title>Change Contents</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("#fs").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform">
    <button>erase</button>
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
        <option value="Impact">Impact </option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>

    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<textarea class="changeMe">Text into textarea</textarea>
<div id="container" class="changeMe">
    <div id="float">
        <p>
            Text into container
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleae initialize your handler in the jQuery ready() clause.

```
$(function() {
});
```

Your code may look like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...

```
<textarea id=ta class="changeMe">Text into textarea</textarea>
<div id="container" class="changeMe">
    <div id="float">
        <p>
            Text into container
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#ta').keyup(function(){
            $('#float').html("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");
        });
        $("#fs").change(function() {
            $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
        });         
        $("#size").change(function() {
            $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other changes :

- use jquery 1.7.1 instead of this old version
- use an id for the text area to detect change
- use "keyup" instead of "change" so that the change is immediate (no need to click outside)

If you want only the div to be changed, simply replace `$('.changeMe')` by `$('#float')` in the two last handlers.

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/YfQfr/ but i want is display the TExtarea content in DIV and change the fonts of that DIV not the Textarea

Comment: I did as per your instruction but it doesnt seems to change the font now "If you want only the div to be changed, simply replace $('.changeMe') by $('#float') in the two last handlers."

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
  // your code goes here
});
```

or alternatively put your code at bottom just before `</body>` tag so that when your code runs, it knows about elements.

The following code should work fine:

```
$(function(){

   $("#fs").change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
     $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
   });

   $("#size").change(function() {
     $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
   });

});
```

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/YfQfr/ but i want is display the TExtarea content in DIV and change the fonts of that DIV not the Textarea

Comment: @user580950: A keypress event to textarea is added, see updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfQfr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your scripts in the header : they're executed before the referenced DOM objects are available.

Put this at the end of your body :

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#fs").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
    $("#size").change(function() {
        $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I put in Body but that didnt help

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/YfQfr/ but i want is display the TExtarea content in DIV and change the fonts of that DIV not the Textarea

Answer (score 0):

Along with what dystroy said, you can also use jQuery(since you taged it as jQuery I presume you use it) [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/YfQfr/ but i want is display the TExtarea content in DIV and change the fonts of that DIV not the Textarea

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me : http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/YfQfr/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fs").live('change', function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());

        });

        $("#size").live('change', function () {
            $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
        });

        $("#fs").trigger('change');

        $("#size").trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks yes it works, but i need is on changing of Text contents i the Text area the same content should be displayed in div id="container"